# Converting an Option<impl Trait> to an Option<Box<dyn Trait>>

Tags: rust

Is it possible to map an `Option<impl Trait>` to a `Option<Box<dyn Trait>>`? If the argument to `new()` is not an `Option`, it is possible to assign it to a `struct` with `Some(Box::new(item))`. Why does this work and the map doesn't?

```
trait TestTrait {}

impl TestTrait for i32 {}

struct TestStruct {
    item: Option<Box<dyn TestTrait>>
}

impl TestStruct {
    pub fn new(item: Option<impl TestTrait + 'static>) -> Self {
        let item: Option<Box<dyn TestTrait>> = item.map(|i| Box::new(i));
        Self {
            item
        }
    }
}


fn main() {    
    let num:i32 = 0;
    let s = TestStruct::new(Some(num));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the compiler can not inference the correct type for the closure. If you specify it explicitly then everything works ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a2b485fff13c67e9d428737b47ff863c)):

```
trait TestTrait {}

impl TestTrait for i32 {}

struct TestStruct {
    item: Option<Box<dyn TestTrait>>
}

impl TestStruct {
    pub fn new(item: Option<impl TestTrait + 'static>) -> Self {
        let item = item.map(
            |i| -> Box<dyn TestTrait> {
                Box::new(i)
            }
        );
        Self {
            item
        }
    }
}

fn main() {    
    let num:i32 = 0;
    let _ = TestStruct::new(Some(num));
}
```

Comment: `Box::new(i) as Box<dyn TestTrait>` will also suffice to prevent the compiler from over-doing type inference.

Comment: Hi @user2722968. Yes, you absolutely right. Also I played with `Box::new::<turbofish>` to remove the closure but without success.